# sqlite database image stored success but update not working.Am store image in blob type

Tags: android, image, sqlite, blob

Am stored image in sqlite database.i stored successfully after that am retrieve image it also working fine.but update the image  not work.i cant find the problem.no error shows  after update  i retrieve image but noting show in image view

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists producttable1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + "subid TEXT,"
        + "submenue  TEXT,"
        + "submenut TEXT,"
        + "status TEXT,"
        + "submenuh TEXT,"
        + "rate TEXT,"
        +"photo BLOB,"      
        + "imgstat TEXT,"
        + "stackstat TEXT," + "noitem TEXT)");
public void addsubmenu(Model md) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("subid", md.subid);
contentValues.put("submenue", md.smenue);
contentValues.put("submenut", md.smenut);
contentValues.put("submenuh", md.smenuh);
contentValues.put("rate", md.rate);
contentValues.put("noitem", md.noitem);
contentValues.put("status", md.status);
contentValues.put("stackstat", md.stackstat);
contentValues.put("photo",md.photo);
contentValues.put("imgstat",md.imgstat);
db.insert("PRODUCTTABLE1", null, contentValues);
db.close();
}
     public void updateitem(Model productList) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
//byte[] byteImage2 = null;
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("id", productList.id);
contentValues.put("smenue", productList.smenue);
contentValues.put("smenut", productList.smenut);
contentValues.put("smenuh", productList.smenuh);
contentValues.put("rate", productList.rate);
contentValues.put("noitem", productList.noitem);
contentValues.put("photo",productList.photo);
contentValues.put("imgstat",productList.imgstat);   









db.execSQL("update producttable1 set submenue='" + productList.smenue
            + "',submenut='" + productList.smenut + "',submenuh='"
            + productList.smenuh + "',photo='"+productList.photo+"',imgstat='"+productList.imgstat+"',rate='" + productList.rate
            + "',noitem='" + productList.noitem + "' where id='"
            + productList.id + "'");    


db.close();
```

}

Comment: Did you check it productList.photo has value at the time of updating?

Comment: not yet...am try now after that send result...thanks for your comment

Comment: am checked it updating  productList.photo have values,,,when retireve it not show

Comment: In sample its working as expected. Still you can try solution.

Comment: am print byte value...but it shows one value for updating and shows onther value for retrieving...i think this maybe issue for image not showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. 
As you have used content values.

```
String where = "id=?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(productList.id)};

db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, contentValues, where, whereArgs);
```